# Trouble downloading Sentinel image from SCP Plugin

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, scp

I am trying to download Sentinel 2 image from SCP Plugin. However when I find the images and try to preview it, it wont appear in the preview panel neither it can be downloaded it says error

Additionally, I cannot login to Copernicus data despite adding coorect username and password (currently I only have Earthdata login). I have already tried checking/unchecking only if previewing in layers.

[image]
[image]